# How to access properties of an arraylist using spring form tags?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

There is a parent bean with some properties,out of those properties one is an `ArrayList`. Now this `ArrayList` is initialized with the properties of a child bean. Now how can i get access to these properties in jsp using spring form tags? Actually i need to iterate through the `ArrayList` and access its properties. My code is given below,

```
 <c:forEach var="documentlist" items="${policydocumentsetform.documentList}">      
 <c:if test="${documentlist.txtDisableCheckBox=='N'}">
   <form:checkbox path="documentlist.ynChkBox" cssClass="genradio" value="-1" onclick="selectCheckBox(event.keyCode,this)"/>
</c:if>
```

The error is being thrown because of this `path="documentlist.ynChkBox"`, please help!!

Comment: In path instead of documentlist.ynChkBox use your model attribute which is related to your tag

Comment: would you please say what do u exactly mean by model attribute ? sorry i am not familiar with the terms...

Comment: The class from where you are creating your table With using annotations @Entity/@Table.
The variable name which present in that class used in your path.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code in jsp, you need to make sure that your form and its properties are as below:

```
    public class Policydocumentsetform implements Serializable{
        ...
                       //I would rather go with List
        private ArrayList<Document> documentList;
        ...
    }
```

where document is the bean containing:

```
    public class Document implements Serializable{
        ...
        private String txtDisableCheckBox;
        private String ynChkBox;
        ...
    }
```

Try this way:

```
    <c:forEach var="document" items="${policydocumentsetform.documentList}" varStatus="documentStatus">      
        <c:if test="${document.txtDisableCheckBox=='N'}">
           <form:checkbox path="document[${documentStatus.index}].ynChkBox" cssClass="genradio" value="-1" onclick="selectCheckBox(event.keyCode,this)"/>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Tried but didn't have success,     org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'document[0]' of bean class (the parent bean)

Comment: To my understanding it is trying to find the property document.ynChkBox in the bean object 'policydocumentsetform' but actually it lies in the bean object 'policydocumentsetchildform' which is used to the initialise the arraylist, property of the 'policydocumentsetform'. So the requirement is to make this path point to the child bean object so that this property could be found.

Comment: Make sure you have properties as mentioned in my answer. By looking at your code in jsp, txtDisableCheckBox and ynChkBox cannot be children of form directly as you are checking conditions for each of the list element - rather children of document list.

Comment: ya thats what i have said in my last comment,txtDisableCheckBox  & ynChkBox are not children of form directly but of another form which is being accessed with the help of a list. Please note that i am dealing with two form beans here,the arraylist is child of the first bean and its contained properties are children of another bean. ur code is giving something like this,'document[0].ynChkBox' ..

Comment: Show your full Jsp and how are child parent forms related?

Comment: can't paste the full jsp here as it too long,given below is the code snippet responsible for the error <c:if test="${policydocumentsetform.txtPageMode=='I'}"><c:if test="${documentlist.txtDisableCheckBox=='N'}"><form:checkbox path="documentlist.ynChkBox" cssClass="genradio" value="-1" onclick="selectCheckBox(event.keyCode,this)"/>
                                    </c:if>c:if test="${documentlist.txtDisableCheckBox=='Y'}"><form:checkbox path="documentlist.ynChkBox" cssClass="genradio" value="-1" disabled="true"/>
                                    </c:if>
                            </c:if>

Comment: This above mentioned jsp has 'policydocumentsetform' as its command name,which is related to the parent form containing the arraylist. The form bean structures whcih u have mentioned earlier is similar to that of mine.

Comment: Your posted code here is not the same as in question. For loop is gone, it's difficult to understand what you are trying to do/achieve.